# How to override "="

Tags: haxe, abstract-type

I was looking into Haxe abstracts and was very interested in building an abstract that would wrap a class and unify it to, in my case, an `Int`.

```
@:forward()
abstract Abs(Op)
{
    public inline function new(value:Int = 0, name:String = "unnamed" )
    {
        this = new Op();
        this.value = value;
        this.name = name;

    }

    @:to
    private inline function toInt():Int
    {
        return this.value;
    }
}

class Op
{
    public var value:Int = 0;
    public var name:String = "no name";

    public function new()
    {

    }
}
```

The problem I ran in to is when defining a `@:from` method - it has to be `static` and can take only one parameter - a new value. So whenever I set the abstract's instance value from the `@:from` method I will have to create a new instance of the abstract, thus resetting all the variables.

Basically what I'm talking about is this:

```
var a = new Abs(5, "my abs"); // value is 5; name is "my abs"
a = 100; // value is 100; name is reset to "unnamed" but I want it to be preserved
```

As much as I could find out we cannot overload the `=` operator in abstracts other than through implicit casting with a `@:from` method and I haven't found a way to really achieve this with macros.

If you have any ideas on how this can be done, please provide a minimalist example.

Comment: As side questions I'm wondering: 
1. I'm curious why you want to have this? 
2. If Op/Abs has two Int properties what is expected behavior?

Comment: 1. It's great utility because of how abstract it is. 2. You set the `@:from` method to the variable you want to represent it as; other variables don't matter as much and can be accessed with the `.` as in `abs.otherIntVariable = 3;`

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to do, but if you use this:

```
var a = new Abs(5, "my abs");
var myInt:Int = a;
```

It will use the abstract `Abs.toInt` function.

```
@:to
private inline function toInt():Int
{
    return this.value;
}
```

The other way around also works:

```
var million = 1000000;
var myAbs:Abs = million;
```

It will use the static `Abs.fromInt` function.

```
@:from
static inline function fromInt(value:Int)
{
    return new Abs(value, "what");
}
```

This is because it uses the implicit cast. http://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract-implicit-casts.html

> Try it yourself: http://try.haxe.org/#Ae1a8

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I guess my English was bad. I want to set instance of Abs to an Int ( it will modify the `value` variable ) and keep all other variables - name in this instance

Comment: In that case you are looking for `@:from` http://try.haxe.org/#Ae1a8 I've updated the answer.

Comment: yes, from does work, but as you saw yourself the `name` variable cannot be copied from the original instance of the abstract due to the nature of the `@:from` method. Please read my question, I explained it there.

Comment: I dont get it, the `@:from` method could also return `return new Abs(value);` if you want the default value? Or do you somehow expect another value there?

Comment: If the underlying type has two public variables: `name` and `value` and your `@:from` method sets the `value` - how can you keep the old `name` property? That's the question.

Comment: I think you cannot do that using the `=` operator. It can only with `value` property on a Abs.

Comment: Unless...macros! :) I'm working on the solution, if nobody gives an answer I'll post my own soon.